# Does Javascript `throw new Error(msg)` require the `new`?

Tags: javascript, syntax, error-handling

I've seen examples of `throw` that use `Error` and `new Error`:

> throw new Error('new Error')

and

> throw Error('Error')

i.e.: 

`(function(){ throw new Error('new Error') })()
(function(){ throw Error('Error') })()`

(cut/paste in console to see that they both work)

Is there any reason to include the `new`?

I ask because I think throwing Errors is preferred to throwing strings .. better stack trace I think, but if the new isn't needed, I'll drop it.

Comment: [What is the difference between \`throw new Error\` and \`throw someObject\` in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9156176)

Comment: Yup it's a dup, thanks! Use the link at the top of the question, not the one directly above.